# Automatic BCC stopped working for a user

Tags: email, einstein-activity-capture

Salesforce has the feature that a user can choose to automatically fill the BCC field for all outgoing emails.
It is set via `Settings > Email > My Email Settings > Would you like to automatically BCC emails to your return address?`

For one of our users, this feature stopped working. The setting still had the value "Yes", but from a certain date, the BCC field was no longer filled automatically.
For other users, it still works.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contact with Salesforce Support, it turns out that for users, for which Einstein Activity Capture has been turned on, the automatic BCC feature no longer works.

For Salesforce this is not a bug, but a feature, as Salesforce Support directed us to an idea to have this "feature" changed: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVlOUAV/inbox-with-einstein-activity-capture-log-to-records-in-the-bcc-field